# getting data from df1 if it doesn't exist in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get data from df1 if it doesn't exist in df2 and col1 in df1 should be aligned with col3 in df2 ( same for col2 and col4)

```
Df1: 

col1  col2   
2     2      
1     Nan    
Nan   1         

Df2:

col3  col4   
Nan   1      
1     Nan    
Nan   1         


Final_Df:

col1  col2   
2     1      
1     Nan    
Nan   1
```

Comment: It seems that your Final_Df is not aligned with what you are requesting: col2 for the first row is updated with Df2's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the column same / replace Nan with np.NAN / update the dataframe

```
df1.columns = df2.columns
df2 = df2.replace('Nan', np.NAN)
df2.update(df1, overwrite=False) # will only update the NAN values
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [pandas.DataFrame.update(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). The overwrite parameter explanation.

> **overwrite** bool, default True
>
> How to handle non-NA values for overlapping keys:
>
> - True: overwrite original DataFrame’s values with values from other.
> - False: only update values that are NA in the original DataFrame.

Note that `df.update(other)` modifies in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame on matching column label.

```py
df2.update(df1.set_axis(df2.columns, axis=1))
```

```
print(df2)

  col3 col4
0    2    2
1    1  Nan
2  Nan    1
```